# Scrapy Tutorial (Python) - ImportError: Error loading object

Tags: python, scrapy

I have to run basic tutorial on the Scrapy architecture Win32.

When I try `scrapy crawl dmoz`, shows me the following error:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 40, in
>   load_object raise ImportError, "Error loading object '%s':% s"% (path,
>   e)
>
> ImportError: Error loading object
>   'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3.S3DownloadHandler': DLL load
>   failed: Could not find the specified module.

The Python version is 2.7, 32 bit on Win 32.

I have installed the following (as [Platform specific installation notes](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#intro-install-platform-notes)):

- pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe
- Twisted-13.1.0.win32-py2.7.exe
- zope.interface-4.0.5.win32-py2.7.exe
- lxml-3.2.3.win32-py2.7.exe
- pyOpenSSL-0.11.winxp32-py2.7.exe

I had the *easy_install* then through it installed pip, and then I did:

```
pip install Scrapy
```

I just made a change. I installed **Zope** .exe as above, then I did not like:

> zope.interface: zope.interface download the egg from pypi page and
>   install it by running easy_install file.egg

Could this be the problem?

Comment: open python in a terminal and type: `import scrapy`. Does that throw an error?

Comment: It sounds like scrapy thinks you have [`boto`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto) installed, but you don't. (I believe it's an optional dependency, that will get used if you have it, but skipped if you don't.) You could try to debug why it got confused… or you could just install `boto` first, then reinstall `scrapy` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @kerolek Does the import, and does not throw errors.

Comment: I've installed scrapy on XP, installing zope using the Windows installer and it was fine. I don't think that is causing the issue.

Comment: @abarnert I did `pip install boto`, `pip unninstall Scrapy` and `pip install Scrapy`, and remained the same error. Do you have any more suggestions for me?

Comment: It might help to `from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers import s3; s3.S3DownloadHandler`, `from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection`, and `import boto.auth` to see where the DLL error is actually coming from. (I'm looking at the source [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/s3.py) to guess what might be relevant.) Also, `import scrapy; print scrapy.optional_features` to see if `'boto'` is in the set.

Comment: I can do from `scrapy.core.downloader.handlers import *`. But `from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers import s3` says:

(...)`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 7, in <module>
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: Could not find the specified module.`

Comment: Try reinstalling Twisted perhaps? Btw what version of scrapy are you using?

Comment: @abarnert I can do `from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers import *`. But `from scrapy.core.downloader.handlers import s3` says:

(...)`File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 7, in <module>
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: Could not find the specified module.`

The rest (about `boto`) imported correctly.

And boto is not in `optional_features`, just: `set(['ssl', 'http11'])`

Comment: Or try reinstalling `pywin32`, which is where `win32api` comes from. But _first_, try the `twisted` and `win32api` imports yourself, just to make sure the problem is consistent and you're not just chasing random packages on a wild goose chase… (PS, hunting down import problems with C extension modules in Python 2.x sucks; in 3.2+ it's usually a lot nicer… I know I'm not going to convince you to switch to 3.x just for that, but one more straw on the camel's back never hurt.)

Comment: @Talvalin the Scrapy version is _Scrapy-0.18.3-py2.7_. Unfortunately the error has not changed when I reinstalled twisted.

Comment: @abarnert I do not know if this is relevant but the log shows the boto: `[scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto`

Comment: @RaulAbreuLeite: Is it possible that `optional_features` didn't have "boto", until I make you unnecessarily install it? Anyway, I think that's probably a red herring… I'm not _sure_, but it seems like the error is elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you both for your patience, understanding my English, and for your time. After reinstall pywin32 it worked. Can anyone tell me what happened here, please? PS I have not found how to put points here for you, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Installing pywin32 solved the problem for me,
It can be downloaded from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. I checked almost all the possible packages and update them to 64-bit. Didn't work. Magical thing happened when I install a 32-bit pywin32. Everything just clicked. I've no idea why. Hope it will help...